# Confusion with matrix derivatives and component-wise gradients

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

According to [this source](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) (The Matrix Cookbook), we have that for $f(X) = \mathbf{a}^T X \mathbf{b}$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, \mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the derivative is $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = \mathbf{a} \mathbf{b}^T$$ which is a scalar since it's basically a dot product. I see how we can arrive at this result by applying matrix derivative rules/applying basic derivative rules to vectors/matrices. However, taking the derivative (gradient) of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}$ based on my my calculus knowledge should yield a vector/matrix of partial derivatives.

As an example, I tried this with $\mathbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \end{bmatrix}, \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$, and $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{bmatrix}$. I expanded the expression and took the gradient to get that $$\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1b_1 & a_1b_2 \\ a_2b_1 & a_2b_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

So, my question is, is this the derivative, or is it $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T$? Should the derivative be a vector or a scalar?

P.S. I also noticed that $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T = \operatorname{trace}(\nabla f)$ for the matrix I computed for $\nabla f$. Is there any significance to that?

Comment: It's not a scalar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is vector usually refers to a column vector (otherwise the expression $a^TXb$ doesn't even make sense since the dimensions don't match). If you instead do
$$ab^T = \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_1 & b_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1b_1 & a_1b_2\\
a_2b_1 & a_2b_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
then you get the same result as your computation.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I was not considering the outer product when I did this, but I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are several competing notations. The notation in Matrix Cookbook can be motivated as follows -- suppose we minimize scalar function of scalar variable $w$ using gradient descent update

$$w\leftarrow w-f'(w)$$

Now, suppose $f(W)$ is a scalar function of matrix variable. We want similar looking update formula to hold

$$W\leftarrow W-f'(W)$$

So this determines the shape of $f'$: $i,j$th entry of $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ w.r.t. to $i,j$the entry of $W$, which gives you $f'(W)=ab^T$ when $f(W)=a'Wb$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain how differentiating $f$ w.r.t the $i,j$th entry of $W$ gives $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T$? Wouldn't that yield the same matrix in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobian matrix is the derivative of a vector function $\pmb{f}$
of a vector $\pmb{x}$:
$$
\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial \pmb{x}^T}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_{2}} \\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} \end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e. the partial derivatives are w.r.t. the *transpose* of the vector. The relation between the
differential of $\pmb{f}$ and the differential of $\pmb{x}$
is,
\begin{align*}
d\pmb{f}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    df_1 \\ df_2
\end{bmatrix}
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} dx_1 +
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} dx_2 \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} dx_1 +
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} dx_2
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} &
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}  \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} &
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    dx_1 \\ dx_2
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial \pmb{x}^T} d\pmb{x}
\end{align*}
which shows that the definition of the derivative of $\pmb{f}$ w.r.t. $\pmb{x}$ as $\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial \pmb{x}^T}$ is correct.

In the same way given $f=\pmb{a}^T\pmb{X}\pmb{b}$ we have,
$$
f = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}X_{11} & X_{12} \\ X_{21} & X_{22} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \pmb{X}^T}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{X_{11}} & \frac{\partial f}{X_{21}} \\ \frac{\partial f}{X_{12}} & \frac{\partial f}{X_{22}} \end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e. the partial derivatives are w.r.t. the transpose of the matrix.
Since,
$$
f=a_1 (b_1X_{11}+b_2X_{12})
+a_2(b_1X_{21}+b_2X_{22})
$$
we have,
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{11}}
    &=
    a_1 b_1  &
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{21}}
    &=
    a_2 b_1  \\
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{12}}
    &=
    a_1 b_2  &
        \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{22}}
    &=
    a_2 b_2  
\end{align*}
and so,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \pmb{X}^T}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_1b_1 & a_2b_1 \\
    a_1b_2 & a_2b_2 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    b_1 \\ b_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\pmb{b}\pmb{a}^T
$$

The differential of $f$,
\begin{align*}
df & = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{11}} d X_{11}
+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{12}} d X_{12}
+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{21}}d X_{21}
+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{22}}d X_{22} \\
& =a_1b_1 dX_{11} + a_1b_2 dX_{12}
+a_2b_1 dX_{21} + a_2b_2 dX_{22} \\
& =\mathrm{tr}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_1b_1 & a_2b_1 \\
    a_1b_2 & a_2b_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    dX_{11} & dX_{12} \\
    dX_{21} & dX_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\right) \\
& = \mathrm{tr}
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \pmb{X}^T}
d\pmb{X}
\right)
\end{align*}
and so defining the derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $\pmb{X}$ as above
generates the correct differential.